# No option for built in server php 5.6

Tags: php, gulp

I have php version 5.6, I am trying to get the built in web server running, BUT I have noticed that there is no option for me to even run it. I apologize, I am a intermediate php guy. I was previously using XAMPP to serve it, but I am trying to incorporate my php development into my gulp workflow with browsersync and gulp-connect-php. Any suggestions are much appreciated and thank you. I have attached my CMD screenshot. 
[image: No run server option.]

Comment: never looked into it, but it's probably a compile-time option to enable/disable the webserver support. maybe yours was built with it disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am stupid. I was looking for the version in the XAMPP admin, which was version 5.6, BUT I only have 5.3 on my machine with the php output -v